# How to prevent setuptools install package as an .egg

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

For example, installing IPython on Linux (where setuptools is not installed) I've got IPython installed in `site-packages\IPython`.

Installing IPython on Windows (where IPython requires setuptools), after executing the same command

```
python setup.py install
```

I get IPython installed in `site-packages\ipython-0.13.2-py2.7.egg\IPython`

Is there a way to install the module "old way" i.e. into `site-packages\IPython`?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez In my application I use embedded python. I want the installed packages to be at the same path (relatively to site-packages) both on Linux and on Windows - it helps me keep simple install rules for my application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've discovered that

```
python setup.py install --old-and-unmanageable
```

does the job, but I am not sure it is a good way as `--old-and-unmanageable` is marked "Try not to use this!".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's applicable in your case, but the `--root` option also does this. For example, the Fedora packaging guidelines make use of this, since the versioning is managed externally by RPM. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python_Eggs