# netifaces import error on android in kivy buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer, python-netifaces

I Have import netifaces in buildozer requirments. But After buillding the app. At the runtime of app, I'm having a problem importing netifaces on android in kivy app. Output is below. Whats this error trying to say. Its gives some error like:

```
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.python-eggs'
```

the following is the full log output of app.

```
 I/python  ( 9404):  Traceback (most recent call last):
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/root/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/netifaces.py", line 7, in <module>
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/netifaces.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1161, in resource_filename
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1861, in get_resource_filename
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1891, in _extract_resource
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1227, in get_cache_path
 I/python  ( 9404):    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1207, in extraction_error
 I/python  ( 9404):  pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache
 I/python  ( 9404):  The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
 I/python  ( 9404):  cache:
 I/python  ( 9404):    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.python-eggs'
 I/python  ( 9404):  
 I/python  ( 9404):  The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:
 I/python  ( 9404):  
 I/python  ( 9404):    /data/.python-eggs
 I/python  ( 9404):  
 I/python  ( 9404):  Perhaps your account does not have write access to  this directory?  You can

 I/python  ( 9404):  change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment

 I/python  ( 9404):  variable to point to an accessible directory.
 I/python  ( 9404):  
 I/python  ( 9404): Python for android ended.
```

i can't understand, what it this? Please can you tell me why this error comes and how can i solve this? i will be very thankful to you if tell me the solution.

here my buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My App

# (str) Package name
package.name = com.example.myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.example.myapp

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,openssl,psutil,pyopenssl,setuptools,python,android,pyjnius,netifaces

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,READ_PHONE_STATE,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 0


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

now you will better understand my problem.

**Edit:**
   After your new suggestion about error, it gives new error in buildozer logcat, it crash my app. Following below is log which got during application launch on device.

```
I/python  ( 4277): presplash-fit is null
I/python  ( 4277): presplash (fit=null) mx=0.468750,my=0.746094
I/libSDL  ( 4277): Physical screen resolution is 480x764
I/python  ( 4277): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  ( 4277): ['/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/site-python']
I/python  ( 4277): Android path ['/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files', '/data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/_applibs']
I/python  ( 4277): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  ( 4277): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  ( 4277): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-06-15_2.txt
I/python  ( 4277): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
I/python  ( 4277): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Jun 15 2016, 21:33:42) 
I/python  ( 4277): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  ( 4277): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
D/AudioHardware(   89): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
D/AudioHardware(   89): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
I/python  ( 4277):  /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
I/python  ( 4277):  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
I/python  ( 4277): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
F/libc    ( 4277): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=14390), thread 4295 (Thread-268)
I/DEBUG   (   84): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   84): Build fingerprint: 'HCM7000HC/HCM7000HC/HCM7000HC:4.1.1/GSDT011/20130802.154043:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   84): pid: 4277, tid: 4295, name: Thread-268  >>> in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer:python <<<
I/DEBUG   (   84): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c
I/DEBUG   (   84):     r0 00000000  r1 5daa60d4  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     r4 400effdb  r5 00000007  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     r8 00000031  r9 587de000  sl 00001084  fp 00003000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     ip 5daa60b8  sp 5daa60b8  lr 400e4ca9  pc 400e4cba  cpsr 40000030
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d0  696c2f73656c6966  d1  6e6f687479702f62
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d2  2d62696c2f372e32  d3  2f64616f6c6e7964
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d4  437f00003f000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d6  437f000043f00000  d7  000000a800000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d16 4065000000000000  d17 4010000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d18 4024000000000000  d19 41d5d8508b000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d20 4000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 bf66c16c16bebd93
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d24 3fc555555555553e  d25 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d26 3fd55555518f264d  d27 3fdb6db6db6fabff
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d28 3fe3333333333303  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     d30 4000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   84):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     #00  pc 00005cba  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   84):     #01  pc 00000507  [vectors]
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6078  5893bed0  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa607c  714613d6  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6080  0000002c  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6084  5db338b4  /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/lib/libpython2.7.so (PyDict_SetItem+228)
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6088  587c4180  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa608c  5cb75dc8  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6090  5cb75dc8  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6094  5893bed0  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6098  57048da0  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa609c  5db34a58  /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/lib/libpython2.7.so
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60a0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60a4  587c4180  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60a8  400effdb  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60ac  00000007  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60b0  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60b4  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (   84):     #00  5daa60b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60bc  587c4180  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60c0  5cb75dc8  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60c4  5893bed0  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60c8  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60cc  5dd3abfc  /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/lib/libpython2.7.so
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60d0  0000002c  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60d4  65726854  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60d8  322d6461  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60dc  00003836  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60e4  57048d00  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60e8  57048d88  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60ec  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60f0  00000008  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa60f4  5887631b  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (   84):     #01  5daa6200  5ac3c35a  /system/framework/framework-res.apk
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6204  5ca88a70  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6208  00000018  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa620c  5ca88a60  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6210  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6214  0000000e  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6218  00000817  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa621c  00001204  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6220  587e2084  /data/data/in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer/files/netifaces.so
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6224  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6228  00000f60  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa622c  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6230  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6234  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa6238  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84):          5daa623c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60b4 e3a070ad 00000000 587c4180 5cb75dc8  .p.......A|X.].\
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60c4 5893bed0 00000001 5dd3abfc 0000002c  ...X.......],...
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60d4 65726854 322d6461 00003836 00000000      Thread-268......
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60e4 57048d00 57048d88 00000000 00000008  ...W...W........
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60f4 5887631b 00000000 57048c50 00000002  .c.X....P..W....
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400effb8 6f626d79 7369206c 746f6e20 6f6c6720  ymbol is not glo
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400effc8 006c6162 49474953 53004c4c 42414749  bal.SIGILL.SIGAB
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400effd8 53005452 55424749 49530053 45504647  RT.SIGBUS.SIGFPE
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400effe8 47495300 56474553 47495300 464b5453  .SIGSEGV.SIGSTKF
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400efff8 5300544c 49504749 3f004550 3c003f3f  LT.SIGPIPE.???.<
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     587ddfe0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     587ddff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     587de000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     587de010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     587de020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00001064 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00001074 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00001084 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00001094 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     000010a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00002fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00002ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00003000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00003010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84):     00003020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa6098 57048da0 5db34a58 00000000 587c4180  ...WXJ.].....A|X
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60a8 400effdb 00000007 df002777 e3a070ad  ...@....w'...p..
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60b8 00000000 587c4180 5cb75dc8 5893bed0  .....A|X.].\...X
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60c8 00000001 5dd3abfc 0000002c 65726854  .......],...Thre
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60d8 322d6461 00003836 00000000 57048d00  ad-268.........W
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa6098 57048da0 5db34a58 00000000 587c4180  ...WXJ.].....A|X
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60a8 400effdb 00000007 df002777 e3a070ad  ...@....w'...p..
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60b8 00000000 587c4180 5cb75dc8 5893bed0  .....A|X.].\...X
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60c8 00000001 5dd3abfc 0000002c 65726854  .......],...Thre
I/DEBUG   (   84):     5daa60d8 322d6461 00003836 00000000 57048d00  ad-268.........W
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4c98 2200447c a9072010 46139200 ebaef000  |D.". .....F....
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4ca8 4963b128 4479a807 eae6f000 f88de001  (.cI..yD........
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4cb8 68f7002c f00068b6 4a5eeb94 a907462b  ,..h.h....^J+F..
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4cc8 447a9104 e88d2180 96020090 a82c9003  ..zD.!........,.
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4cd8 fd0ef7ff aa2c4958 44792007 f8acf001  ....XI,.. yD....
I/DEBUG   (   84): 
I/DEBUG   (   84): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4c88 4c68e007 e004447c 447c4c67 4c67e001  ..hL|D..gL|D..gL
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4c98 2200447c a9072010 46139200 ebaef000  |D.". .....F....
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4ca8 4963b128 4479a807 eae6f000 f88de001  (.cI..yD........
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4cb8 68f7002c f00068b6 4a5eeb94 a907462b  ,..h.h....^J+F..
I/DEBUG   (   84):     400e4cc8 447a9104 e88d2180 96020090 a82c9003  ..zD.!........,.
I/BootReceiver(  259): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/DropBoxManagerService(  259): Dropping: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE (10 > 0 bytes)
I/WindowState(  259): WIN DEATH: Window{4178f2a8 SurfaceView paused=false}
I/ActivityManager(  259): Process in.technhack.mobileinformer.in.technhack.mobileinformer:python (pid 4277) has died.
```

I think it is error of debugging, but how can i solve this.

Comment: Does a simple app without any package work for you, or do you get `Permission denied` for those too? The error is clear, it tries to extract egg to a folder that it doesn't have permission to write to. A spec would be nice too.

Comment: yes it works without any error, but i got error only in this package netifaces, when i add in buildozer requirements. i don't get error from any other package which add in buildozer requirements. and what is this 'egg'? and why i am not getting permission to write. i need to import this package in my app because it is needed. I am editing my question, i am adding buildozer.spec in my question. So you can understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear, it tries to extract egg to a folder that it doesn't have permission to write to.

Python `.egg` is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051195/5994041), however it seemed kind of weird that other packages work and this one somehow... doesn't.

I looked at its code and it's [not pure-python](https://github.com/renpy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/netifaces/recipe.sh) however and as I see the recipe's comment, the author mentioned that the recipe creates an `egg` and doesn't install it.

You can look at other recipes, find what's missing and test it. If it runs, the recipe should be ok. Try add `-v` at the end of [this line](https://github.com/renpy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/netifaces/recipe.sh#L30) as I find it in some packages containg C code.

**Edit:**

I maybe found a way(or two) how to do this without `.egg` file. I haven't tried it yet because I don't have VM right now. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342941/5994041). Make a backup of the recipe you have in your buildozer's p4a installation and then edit the netifaces recipe:

change [this](https://github.com/renpy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/netifaces/recipe.sh#L34) to:

```
try $BUILD_hostpython/hostpython setup.py install -O2 --prefix $BUILD_PATH/python-install --old-and-unmanageable
```

If it doesn't work, then try to make a different change to the recipe. Change [this](https://github.com/renpy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/netifaces/recipe.sh#L30) to:

```
try $BUILD_hostpython/hostpython setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

then run buildozer, let it create the app, but do not play with it yet. Go through the `.buildozer` folder(I think?) where p4a installation should be(if not, then look into `home/` folder maybe `.python-for-android` will be there). You need to find the source code for `netifaces`, because that should now contain compiled stuff(`.o` and/or `.so` files).

If you find them, then it's the folder you want. Copy the whole `netifaces` folder that contains compiled files to your app's folder, delete `netifaces` from `requirements` in `.spec` and run the buildozer again. Hopefully it'll work.

For each recipe change you should clean the cached files of the `netifaces` package, because it will contain old files and probably even the `.egg` file.

Also you should check [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=kivy), maybe someone had the same problem or knows how to fix that recipe.

Comment: it doesn't work.  i add -v at the end of the line. but it doesn't work for me. Any other solution for this.

Comment: Well either you'll edit the recipe so it works for you, or try even `export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/python-eggs`(same as `export` SDK) as the error says to you. Hopefully it'll work.

Comment: where should add this line. in recipe.sh file of netifaces? can you please tell me that. `export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/python-eggs` and please tell me the line where i add it. please sir

Comment: Just before you run buildozer write to bash that export line.

Comment: but which bash file? i didn't getting it. how to add it i am still not getting it. Please tell in which file i want to add this line. Buildozer.spec or distribute.sh.

Comment: None of them. You write that line before you do anything with buildozer. E.g. `export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/python-eggs` and then `buildozer init` and other commands. No file, just console.

Comment: Thanks for help sir. I will try and tell you what happen And sorry for asking so many question.

Comment: it still give same error. `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/.python-eggs'` Now what can i do. I have write in terminal first `export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/python-eggs` then `buildozer init` and i have create buildozer.spec again and run command `buildozer android debug deploy run logact` but it still give me error in log that. It give same error as i am getting every time. why it is not working i dont know.

Comment: The error means that it's trying to extract the egg on the device, but to an unavailable path, so you'd need to set that env var on the device. You could try doing it before your imports in your python script, but I don't know when it's accessed (that may already be too late).

Comment: Maybe you could use `build_ext --inplace` at first run of the buildozer (it'd compile) and then you'd paste the folder with compiled package into your folder and excluded that package from spec(so that it'd not compile again and the egg error wouldn't appear) and then you'd have compiled package inside the folder which contains `main.py`. However, I didn't try it, so... Or maybe a better one - if the package _is_ already compiled, you'd only need to copy the folder with compiled package to your app folder and exclude from spec.

Comment: where i use this command `build_ext --inplace`. In terminal or in any scrpit? i try this command in terminal before use of `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat` command. but it gives me `bash: build_ext: command not found` so can you tell me sir how can i use this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think this time it will work me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me know if it works and if, then which option. May be useful to at least comment the recipe if not even rewrite it.

Comment: How can add `netifaces.so` file in `buildozer.spec` file. In `# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas` or in `# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec` where add this file.

Comment: `source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,so,o` because without this it'll leave those files out.

Comment: and sir i got only netifaces.so file, i didn't get netifaces.o file. where i find this file. Is it require for app.

Comment: I'm not sure where the recipe generates one - should be near `.so`, but it was mentioned in the recipe. Try to run it only with `.so` file.

Comment: I got again some error or log in buildozer logcat. My app again crash. This it gives some new error. I'm editing my question. You see there what is that error.

Comment: Sorry, I've never got `tombstone` in logcat, don't know about this error anything. O.o

Comment: Is there any other way to import netifaces for android app in kivy buildozer

Comment: Nope, you need to compile it - a recipe is needed. There is that recipe with egg, but obviously it doesn't work for you.

Comment: ok sir got it, Can you suggest me a python network library from which i can get Mac-address, Gateway address, SUbnet mask, broadcast address, etc etc which can use in my kivy aplication.

Comment: @NikeshNayak Netifaces recipe was changed (and I think it depends on python 2.7.11), but now it may be good to go for you -  [PR](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/783/files)

Comment: really, so i can use this lib in android using buildozer? i want to update python-for-android for that?

Comment: I just saw that the warning about egg isn't there, so I'd give it a try.

Comment: ok, so how can get this recepie, my buildozer is cloning old_tool chain. So how can get the updated recepie of netifaces.